# How to write custom printf?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a problem. I try to make custom `printf()` but when I compile this code, the output doesn't seem to come as predicted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void print(char *, ...);

int main()
{
    char str[12]="World";
    char c='A';
    int i=100;
    print("Hello %s %c", str, c);
}

void print(char *c, ...)
{
    char *s;
    va_list lst;
    va_start(lst, c);
    while(*c!='\0')
    {
        if(*c!='%')
        {
            putchar(*c);
            c++;
            continue;
        }
        c++;
        switch(*c)
        {
        case 's': fputs(va_arg(lst, char *), stdout); break;
        case 'c': putchar(va_arg(lst, int)); break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Output which seem to come:Hello World
Output: Hello Worlds Ac
I can't figure out why 's, c' appears.

Comment: If you don't want to re-invent `printf`, you might try http://c-faq.com/varargs/vprintf.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't incrementing the pointer `c` after your switch case, so the while loop runs again for the characters you are using as options.

Just add `c++` after your switch case, like so:

```c
void print(char *c, ...)
{
    char *s;
    va_list lst;
    va_start(lst, c);
    while(*c!='\0')
    {
        if(*c!='%')
        {
            putchar(*c);
            c++;
            continue;
        }
        c++;
        switch(*c)
        {
            case 's': fputs(va_arg(lst, char *), stdout); break;
            case 'c': putchar(va_arg(lst, int)); break;
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

After making this change, I would recommend finding some way of also handling the case where the `%` appears at the end of the string, to avoid running into a buffer overflow. For example, before the switch, maybe check if we have reached a null terminator, and if so, break out of the loop.

```c
void print(char *c, ...)
{
    char *s;
    va_list lst;
    va_start(lst, c);
    while(*c != '\0')
    {
        if(*c != '%')
        {
            putchar(*c);
            c++;
            continue;
        }

        c++;

        if(*c == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }

        switch(*c)
        {
            case 's': fputs(va_arg(lst, char *), stdout); break;
            case 'c': putchar(va_arg(lst, int)); break;
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "c++", loved it

Answer (score -1):

```
void print(char *format, ...)
{
    char *traverse;
    unsigned int i;
    char *s;
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, format);

    for (traverse = format; *traverse != '\0'; traverse++)
    {
        while (*traverse != '%')
        {
            putchar(*traverse);
            traverse++;
        }
        traverse++;
        switch (*traverse)
        {
        case 's':
            s = va_arg(arg, char *);
            puts(s);
            break;
        case 'c':
            putchar(va_arg(lst, int));
            break;
        }
        va_end(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).